# how to get parse this span id element with jsoup in android studio?

Tags: java, html, android-studio, jsoup

I want to parse the span id = shd2b from this url in my android studio project,
https://www.exchangerates.org.uk/Euros-to-Rupees-currency-conversion-page.html

[Screenshot in link below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBnJD.png)

I used the below java code to parse it and display in a textview box.

```js
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //Connect to the website
            String url = "https://www.exchangerates.org.uk/Euros-to-Rupees-currency-conversion-page.html";
            //Get the title of the website
            Document doc = null;
            doc = (Document) Jsoup.parse(url);
            eurotoinr = doc.getElementById("span.shd2b");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            textView.setText((CharSequence) eurotoinr);
        }
```

Bu nothing is displayed in the emulator device when i run it. Could someone please help me with this issue?

Please forgive me if my description is not clear or not understandable. I started learning android studio only during this lockdown and new to stack overflow.

Comment: `span` is not part of the id. The id is just `"shd2b"`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The id is `"shd2b;"`.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the response. Yes I noticed the mistake in span id. I modified the span id and changed doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); in my code. When I tried to execute the code again, the textview is not displaying the span id content. When i try to parse the title using eurotoinr = document.title(); the title of the url is displayed correctly. I don't know exactly where I am making a mistake. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two mistakes.

1. Did you try to debug or display how your document looks after parsing? It look like this:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  https://www.exchangerates.org.uk/Euros-to-Rupees-currency-conversion-page.html
 </body>
</html>
```

because you used wrong method and your string is parsed as HTML fragment. It doesn't try do download anything.
You should use

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Then it downloads the HTML and parses correctly.

2. Your code `doc.getElementById("span.shd2b");` will return null because `span.shd2b` is not a valid id. The id is `shd2b;`
   Use `doc.getElementById("shd2b;");` and it selects expected element:

```
<span id="shd2b;">82.9337</span>
```

Comment: eurotoinr = document.getElementById("shd2b;"); doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); Made these two changes in my program, but nothing is displayed inside the textview box and the app crashes in my emulator after few seconds. Please help me

Comment: Looks like a matter for a separate question because it's not related to jsoup anymore. If you liked this answer remember to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).